# Using two DataList in the same aspx page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a aspx page which has two datalist.The first DataList works perfectly fine but the latter datalist displays nothing.Even wrong syntax goes unnoticed.

```
 <div class=" container col-lg-offset-1">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-6 maincont" >
     <div class="col-lg-6 plcont ">

       <asp:DataList ID="profileDl" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="findMYcontrol" >
          <ItemTemplate>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 plcontTop col-lg-offset-3 " >

               <asp:Image ID="imgP" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pp_path")%>' Height="200px" Width="250px" />
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 plcontButt" >

                <asp:FileUpload ID="profileUP" runat="server"/>
                <asp:Button ID="imgbutt" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" OnClick="picClick" Text="Upload" />

                <p class="profile_lbl"><b>Name: </b><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/><br /> </p>
                <p class="profile_lbl"><b>Email: </b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email")%>' /><br/></p>
                <p class="profile_lbl"><b>Address: </b><asp:Label  ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address")%>' /><br/></p>
                <p class="profile_lbl"><b>Sex: </b><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex")%>' /><br/></p>



            </div>
         </div>

         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:DataList>
      </div>

     <div class="col-lg-6 prcont">

       <asp:DataList ID="dl_commentP" runat="server" >
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="asda" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ecomment")%>' ></asp:Label>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 comment " style=" color:Orange; " >
                 <%-- <asp:Label ID="lblcmt" Text='<%#Eval("ec")%>' 6atsya 
                </div>
             </div>

          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>

     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

In the above code the first datalist is working as it is supposed to but the second datalist in not responding anything even if i make syntax error or even i just place Text in the label like `asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="helo" />` .Its like the datalist dosent even exist.

Comment: How do you bind data to the data list?

Comment: ok let me edit the post to show code behind

Comment: Is it possible that the data source of the second datalist is empty?

Comment: Sorry mybad i was working on wrong file.There was no databinding done in the correct file.